# fortran type*N notation

Tags: types, fortran, portability

I've read many times that using `type*N` notation (`real*8`, complex*16 and the like) may lead to portability problems. Did anybody here ever had a problem with these, which was then solvable by using `kind`s?

Answer (score 5):

I can't say that I've had a problem with this particular issue.  As far as I am aware all the currently active Fortran compilers understand this non-standard way of defining kinds.

But, over the years, I've had my fill of non-standard portability issues.  These days I never (well, very rarely) use non-standard features and I certainly don't declare kinds this way.  I'll typically only use non-standard features if there is a compelling advantage to them, I see no such advantage here.  The only kinds of advantage which might be compelling are matters such as improving execution speed, doing things which are difficult (or impossible) in standard Fortran, genuine extensions to the language's capabilities.  Programmer convenience is not a compelling advantage.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate: I (personally) don't see `real*8` as simply convenience.  It is a little more explicit about what I want -- a floating point number that occupies 8 bytes instead of the usual 4.  Compare `real*8` to `real(kind=selected_real_kind(15))`.  Which one makes more sense?  Since code is read more often than it is written, It is sensible for it to be more easily understood.

Comment: You say potatoes I say potatoes.

Comment: The philosophy of the language is to specify the precision that you need.  For reals in decimal digits.  Then the compiler figures out what type to provide.   Programmers are overwhelming used to thinking in the common types, e.g., 4-byte single precision, 8-byte double, so this hasn't been popular.   Fortran 2008 now provides named kind values that programmers want:  INT8, INT16, INT32, INT64 and REAL32, REAL64, REAL128.   See the "Intrinsic Modules" Chapter of the gfortran manual.

Comment: @mgilson: Well, the problem is that the standard doesn't say what real*N means, as it's a non-standard extension (albeit a common one supported by most compilers). Is N the number of bytes, in which case the obvious follow-up question is, how many bits are there in a byte? Or is it octets? Or bits? Today, where 8-bit bytes are more or less universal and CPU architectures support IEEE 754, and power-of-two sized integer types etc., much of this is irrelevant in 99.99% of all cases. But, as it's straightforward to use the standard kind mechanisms instead of this, why bother worrying?

Comment: @janneb -- I'm just saying that it is a confusing syntax.  When working with people who are unwilling to learn something new, it sometimes makes sense to stand by widely supported extensions (if only to not confuse your colleagues).  Also, if a compiler implemented real*8 as something other than an 8 byte real, there would be quite an uprising due to legacy codes which use it widely...so I don't see that as much of a problem either.